# From the leakCanary report How to understand which objects are garbage collected and which are not ?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, heap-memory, leakcanary

Here is my Code . I need to understand which objects are Garbage collected and which are not. Which objects values are assigned **null** here , are they garbage collected ? By observing this report how to understand which methods , classes are garbage collected or not  . where can I get a resource to understand the report ?

```
* Details:
* Class android.widget.Toast
|   static TAG = "Toast"
|   static localLOGV = false
|   static tContext = .MainActivity@315173888 (0x12c92c00)
|   static LENGTH_LONG = 1
|   static $classOverhead = byte[253]@1872109697 (0x6f962081)
|   static sService = android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy@319801664 (0x130fc940)
|   static LENGTH_SHORT = 0
* Instance of .MainActivity
|   static $assertionsDisabled = false
|   static $classOverhead = byte[3993]@314712065 (0x12c22001)
|   AllActivityFinisherThread = null
|   One_Hour = .MainActivity$14@314592800 (0x12c04e20)
|   RB1Hour = null
|   RB2H = null
|   RBInfinite = null
|   RBThirty = null
|   b = 0.13
|   billingManager =  (0x12c486c0)
|   bottomNavHider = null
|   bottomNavigation = android.widget.LinearLayout@316131328 (0x12d7c800)
|   bought = false
|   brightnesText = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@316130304 (0x12d7c400)
|   brightness = android.widget.LinearLayout@315821056 (0x12d30c00)
|   brightnessHider = null
|   brightnessParam = android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams@315992000 (0x12d5a7c0)
|   btnClosePopup = null
|   btnOK = null
|   cancel = false
|   cancel_button_click_listener = MainActivity$10@314592864 (0x12c04e60)
|   color = android.widget.LinearLayout@316139520 (0x12d7e800)
|   customPagerAdapter = .mineViewPager.CustomPagerAdapter@316966080 (0x12e484c0)
|   doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = java.lang.Boolean@1871492440 (0x6f8cb558)
|   finalSelectedButton = 0
|   firebaseAnalytics = com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics@315593984 (0x12cf9500)
|   hide_bright = android.view.animation.AnimationSet@315020048 (0x12c6d310)
|   hourEt = null
|   i = 0
|   in_app_broadcast_cached = .MainActivity$InAppBroadCastCached@320842432 (0x131faac0)
|   in_app_broadcast_completed = MainActivity$InAppBroadCastCompleted@320842144 (0x131fa9a0)
|   in_app_broadcast_internet = .MainActivity$InAppBroadCastInternet@320842288 (0x131faa30)
|   in_app_broadcast_not_cached = MainActivity$InAppBroadCastNotCached@320842360 (0x131faa78)
|   in_app_broadcast_owner = .MainActivity$InAppBroadCastOwner@320842216 (0x131fa9e8)
|   infinite = MainActivity$12@314592832 (0x12c04e40)
|   infinite_btn_flag = true
|   isAnyAlertDialogShowing = false
|   isFinish = false
|   isTimerAlertDialogShowing = false
|   isanyRadioButtonSelected = true
|   layout = android.widget.RelativeLayout@315757568 (0x12d21400)
|   localBroadcastManager = android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager@315056640 (0x12c76200)
|   mAdView = com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView@315756544 (0x12d21000)
|   minuteEt = null
|   more = android.widget.LinearLayout@316152832 (0x12d81c00)
|   music = android.widget.LinearLayout@316143616 (0x12d7f800)
|   myRadioButtons = null
|   myRunnablePostDelayed = null
|   mySharedPreference = sharedPreference.MySharedPreference@314843848 (0x12c422c8)
|   myTimerBroadCast = MainActivity$MyTimerBroadCast@320842072 (0x131fa958)
|   myTimerThread = null
|   radioHour = 0
|   radioMinute = 0
|   remainingHourforThread = 0
|   remainingMinuteforThread = 0
|   remainingSecondforThread = 0
|   removeAdflag = false
|   restore = null
|   selectedButton = -1
|   setTimerFlag = false
|   set_timer = MainActivity$11@314592848 (0x12c04e50)
|   shouldBottomNavVisibleAlready = false
|   show_bright = android.view.animation.AnimationSet@315019904 (0x12c6d280)
|   slideDown = android.view.animation.AnimationSet@315020336 (0x12c6d430)
|   slideUp = android.view.animation.AnimationSet@315020192 (0x12c6d3a0)
|   testHour = -1
|   testMinute = -1
|   thirty_minute = MainActivity$13@314592816 (0x12c04e30)
|   timeInMilli = 100
|   timeInMilliTemporary = 100
|   timeInMillishelper = 0
|   timer = android.widget.LinearLayout@316134400 (0x12d7d400)
|   timerAlertDialog = null
|   timerTVBottomNav = null
|   timerlayourt = null
|   titleTimer = null
|   tv_remaining_hour = null
|   tv_remaining_minute = null
|   tv_remaining_second = null
|   two_hour = MainActivity$15@314592784 (0x12c04e10)
|   vanisherflag = true
|   viewPager = android.support.v4.view.ViewPager@315753472 (0x12d20400)
|   viewPagerOntouchLsitener = MainActivity$17@314581176 (0x12c020b8)
|   viewpagerPageChanged = MainActivity$16@314592768 (0x12c04e00)
|   window = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow@316066000 (0x12d6c8d0)
|   mDelegate = android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl@315021200 (0x12c6d790)
|   mResources = null
|   mThemeId = 2131820881
|   mCreated = true
|   mFragments = android.support.v4.app.FragmentController@314592880 (0x12c04e70)
|   mHandler = android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$1@314870848 (0x12c48c40)
|   mNextCandidateRequestIndex = 0
|   mPendingFragmentActivityResults = android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat@314844136 (0x12c423e8)
|   mRequestedPermissionsFromFragment = false
|   mResumed = false
|   mStartedActivityFromFragment = false
|   mStartedIntentSenderFromFragment = false
|   mStopped = true
|   mViewModelStore = null
|   mExtraDataMap = android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap@314581872 (0x12c02370)
|   mLifecycleRegistry = android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry@314871456 (0x12c48ea0)
|   mActionBar = null
|   mActionModeTypeStarting = 0
|   mActivityInfo = android.content.pm.ActivityInfo@315022352 (0x12c6dc10)
|   mActivityTransitionState = android.app.ActivityTransitionState@314800608 (0x12c379e0)
|   mApplication = DetectLeak@314870272 (0x12c48a00)
|   mCalled = true
|   mChangeCanvasToTranslucent = false
|   mChangingConfigurations = false
|   mComponent = android.content.ComponentName@314752688 (0x12c2beb0)
|   mConfigChangeFlags = 0
|   mCurrentConfig = android.content.res.Configuration@315281760 (0x12cad160)
|   mDecor = null
|   mDefaultKeyMode = 0
|   mDefaultKeySsb = null
|   mDestroyed = true
|   mDoReportFullyDrawn = false
|   mEatKeyUpEvent = false
|   mEmbeddedID = null
|   mEnableDefaultActionBarUp = false
|   mEnterTransitionListener = android.app.SharedElementCallback$1@1871560280 (0x6f8dbe58)
|   mExitTransitionListener = android.app.SharedElementCallback$1@1871560280 (0x6f8dbe58)
|   mFinished = true
|   mFragments = android.app.FragmentController@314593056 (0x12c04f20)
|   mHandler = android.os.Handler@314740864 (0x12c29080)
|   mHasCurrentPermissionsRequest = false
|   mIdent = 225691438
|   mInstanceTracker = android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker@314593040 (0x12c04f10)
|   mInstrumentation = android.app.Instrumentation@314908952 (0x12c52118)
|   mIntent = android.content.Intent@315084744 (0x12c7cfc8)
|   mLastNonConfigurationInstances = null
|   mMainThread = android.app.ActivityThread@314806624 (0x12c39160)
|   mManagedCursors = java.util.ArrayList@314581920 (0x12c023a0)
|   mManagedDialogs = null
|   mMenuInflater = null
|   mParent = null
|   mReferrer = ""
|   mResultCode = 0
|   mResultData = null
|   mResumed = false
|   mSearchEvent = null
|   mSearchManager = null
|   mStartedActivity = false
|   mStopped = true
|   mTaskDescription = android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription@314740832 (0x12c29060)
|   mTemporaryPause = false
|   mTitle = "Table Lamp"
|   mTitleColor = 0
|   mTitleReady = true
|   mToken = android.os.BinderProxy@314758016 (0x12c2d380)
|   mTranslucentCallback = null
|   mUiThread = java.lang.Thread@1959512464 (0x74cbc990)
|   mVisibleBehind = false
|   mVisibleFromClient = true
|   mVisibleFromServer = true
|   mVoiceInteractor = null
|   mWindow = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow@316066000 (0x12d6c8d0)
|   mWindowAdded = true
|   mWindowManager = android.view.WindowManagerImpl@314845696 (0x12c42a00)
|   mInflater = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater@314754624 (0x12c2c640)
|   mOverrideConfiguration = null
|   mResources = android.content.res.Resources@315519552 (0x12ce7240)
|   mTheme = android.content.res.Resources$Theme@314591872 (0x12c04a80)
|   mThemeResource = 2131820881
|   mBase = android.app.ContextImpl@314672624 (0x12c185f0)
|   shadow$_klass_ = MainActivity
|   shadow$_monitor_ = -1952112838
* Excluded Refs:
| Field: android.os.Message.obj
| Field: android.os.Message.next
| Field: android.os.Message.target
| Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mNextServedView
| Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedView
| Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedInputConnection
| Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mCurRootView
| Field: android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.this$1
| Field: android.os.UserManager.mContext
| Field: com.android.internal.policy.BackdropFrameRenderer.mDecorView
| Field: android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.mMessageQueue
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to check the ["Where can I learn more? - square/leakcanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/wiki/FAQ#where-can-i-learn-more) section at the LeakCanary repository.

If you look at the fields of the MainActivity's instance you can see `mStopped = true` and `mDestroyed = true`. The [documentation for `onDestroy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy()) states:

> Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed.

As `mDestroyed` is true we can conclude that this instance should be ready to be gc'ed but something is preventing this. It's kinda hard to find the reason for this without seeing the source code so feel free to edit your questino with it if you'd like some support with resolving this leak.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Which variables are showing value assigned, they are not garbage collected and which are showing null, they are already garbage collected, Am I right?

Comment: In my experience it's true that variables showing null *will* be garbage collected as there is no reference pointing at them often. But not every variable has to be `null` to be garbage collected, for instance your field `b = 0.13` is not null but will get garbage collected if there is no reference pointing to it. I recommend to what the memory leak live investigation linked on the LeakCanary repo that a better understanding of memory leaks and what is causing them.